# SSRS Drillthrough Report with one or more charts from Main Report

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, ssrs-2012, drillthrough

I am totally new to **SSRS**. I am not sure if my title explains what I want. I am creating few Dashboards for my Healthcare Database. Therefore I created a **Patient summary** report and a **Patient details** report.

Patient summary has:

1. One Pie chart that contains No of Patients(values) per Race(series)
2. Another Pie chart which contains No of Patients(values) per gender(series)

Patient details has:

1. One table which contains

   - Admission type (in-patient/out/patient) as the 1st row drill down.
   - Status(Alive/Dead) as the Second row drill down.
2. It also containes two parameters on Race and Gender which both accept Null or Empty values.

In the main report, I have already set the "Action" in the Pie charts series category and added the parameters Race and Gender respectively.

My problem is that when I click on one pie chart I am getting an error saying the other value is blank. That is, when I click on the Male portion of the gender pie chart, I am getting an error saying

`"The 'Race' parameter is missing a value"`

I have tried searching but found only methods to pass multi-valued single parameter values.
I am not sure how to pass two parameters from the main report to the child report by clicking the 2 pie charts. Some one please let me know if it is even feasible or not and point me in the right direction. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the parameters Race & Gender resides from same dataset?

Comment: @daniel_aren - yes they are from the same dataset

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying both parameters for each pie chart Action, SSRS is expecting a value to be passed for both.

It sounds like you need to remove one of the parameters from the "Action" setting on the pie charts. If your subreport parameters are set to allow null values then you should only need to specify the parameters you actually want to pass, e.g. "Race" on the race pie chart.

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusing. I am **NOT** specifying both parameters for each pie chart. I only have "Race" parameter in the Race pie chart and only "Gender" parameter in the gender pie chart. I meant that my subreport contains "Race" and "Gender" parameters which accept Null values. I was trying to achieve navigation from main report to subreport through either of the pie chart. That is if I click on race chart I want to filter subreport by that race. If i click on gender chart then I want to filter subreport by that gender. Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: In that case what you are describing should work. I have replicated what your scenario by having report A with a pie chart for Gender and report B with two parameters Gender and Race. The parameters on report B are both set to "Allow blank value" and "Allow null value". If I create an Action on the pie chart in report A, specifying "Go to report" for report B and adding only one parameter (Gender), I am able to run report A and clicking on the pie chart drills through to report B. So I can only conclude there must be something else amiss. Are you able to attach any screen shots of settings?

Comment: Please try with having 2 pie charts in report A (which is what am trying to do). One for gender and another for race. Then having "Actions" on both pie charts with parameters gender and race respectively. The other settings are exactly the same. Please let me know if it works

Comment: My version also works with two pie charts, one for "Gender" and one for "Race", as you described. Have you specified "Available Values" for the report 2 parameters? If so, then you will have to supply a value for both parameters. Try adding an "All" option to the available values for the parameters and passing that from the pie charts.

Comment: I sorry I am very new to SSRS. I don't understand what you mean by "Try adding ALL option to available values...". I understand that i need to supply value for both parameters but when i click on one pie chart it quickly goes to the subreport so I am not able to give the value for other parameter. How do I make sure the main report waits until I click on both pie charts or make it just filter the subreport based on the pie chart I clicked and ignore the second pie chart? Hope you understand my question. Sorry again am very new to this.Please explain. Thank you

Comment: Have you specified "Available Values" for the parameters in the second report?

Comment: yes I have. I chose "Get values from a query" option and chose Race column from a dataset.

Comment: Ok, so that is at least part of the problem. If you have specified Available Values for the parameters, then you must supply at least one of those values to the second report otherwise it will not run. So, you need to pass both parameters for each pie chart. The Race pie chart is easy, as you just need to pass both possible values for Gender (i.e. all Genders).

Comment: For Race, perhaps you can create the same Race parameter on your first report, set it to Hidden and use the same dataset you used for Available Values to also set Default Values (i.e. set the parameter to include all vlaues for Race). Then on the Gender pie chart add the Race parameter to the action and set the value to the Race parameter in the first report (i.e. you are passing the value of the hidden parameter in the first report into the same parameter in the second report).

Comment: Please let me know if I understand you properly. You are asking me to keep the 2 pie charts in the main report (one for gender, one for race). create 2 hidden race and gender parameters in the main report. set available values and default values from same dataset. set action in each pie chart with 2 parameters for gender and race. For the values of these parameters (which are passed to the subreport) I should get them from the hidden parameters which I created in this main report itself. Please let me know if this is correct?

Comment: Based on what you have said, that should work. I should add that it is very difficult to give an exact solution to your problem as we cannot see exactly what you have done. However in theory you should be able to do what you described in your original question, therefore a bit of trial and error on your part is required to get it to work. Perhaps you could temporarily remove one pie chart to simplify things and see if you can get the remaining one working first, then add the second chart.

Comment: Single pie chart works fine from the start. It is just the second one. Ill try again. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. Please edit the answer to a more appropriate one following our discussions so that I could accept it for the befit of others in future. Thank u so much for the help again.